# Can I upgrade my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server to 18.04 LTS using ISO file without losing my data?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, server, upgrade, iso

I have done quite a lot of research on upgrading my existing 16.04 LTS Server to 18.04 LTS using the ISO file. My Server does not connect to the internet. Thus I am finding the alternative to upgrade to 18.04 LTS. But still, I can't find the latest procedure on how to upgrade using the ISO file.

I did found out the ancient method which using these steps

- sudo mkdir -p /media/cdrom
- sudo mount -o loop ~/Desktop/ubuntu-11.04-alternate-i386.iso /media/cdrom
- gksu "sh /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade" OR kdesudo "sh /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade"

I did try, but there is nothing pop out for asking me to upgrade. I can only see that I have mounted the ISO into my 16.04 LTS Server.
Can someone please advise me on how am I going to solve this without reformatting and losing all my data in my Server?
Thank you so much. =)

Comment: First of all, **you should have backups**. That said, you can booot the installer and not format the partitions, thus effectively doing a release upgrade and keeping user data, not additionally installed software that has to be reinstalled but the settings are preserved.

Comment: Any time you install operating systems or make changes to partitions there is an increased risk of data loss because something could go wrong or you can make a mistake. This is also true all the time.  By not having backups, data loss is inevitable. It's a matter of when, not if.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu does not guarantee that your data will be preserved across a release-upgrade.

No Ubuntu expert has tested a release-upgrade on your particular mixture of hardware and software.

Maybe the release-upgrade will be successful. Maybe it won't.

Maybe your data will be preserved. Maybe it won't.

Advice: Be prepared for the worst before you hope for the best.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I just want to check is there alternative method by using OS ISO file to upgrade my current OS (not fresh install)? I could finding any updated information on this. =(

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to upgrade from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS without losing you data, but you can do this:

1. Note down the configuration and apps installed on your server
2. Get an Ubuntu Desktop installation drive, select `Try Ubuntu without installing`, then open `disks`, then mount the Ubuntu server drive, backup your data on an USB
3. Do a clean installation of Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS
4. Set the configuration and install the apps on your Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS
5. Get the data from the USB by Ubuntu Desktop installation drive and move it to Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS drive

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Thanks for sharing with me on this. This mean whenever I want to upgrade a old version of Ubuntu to the newer/latest version of Ubuntu, I would need to install clean (new) OS? Am I right to say that? >___< my server data got almost 500+GB.. *fainted*

Comment: umm.. yes, this works